# Magetno 2 base url 302 redirection

Tags: magento2, url, base-url

Hi I am trying to implement add extra key to base url 
example 
**my base url:: abcd.com**
if user click on any key with **base_url** like below
**user entered url :: pawan.abcd.com** site need set new theme if pawan key found my custom table. If not fount i need to redirect to home page or base url means site will work regular format if key found only new theme will assign 
can you please tell how can achieve this.

Present my site abcd.com if i click pawan.abcd.com it redirecting to abcd.com 
i am not redirecting but it redirecting automatically i have installed wild card ssl like ***.abcd.com**

can any one tell how to stop that automatic redirection

Comment: i think you are talking about multi-site which is covered here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

Comment: @Anthony i dont want multi site i know that concept.for every master customer they able to give their name to in-front of base url.example i am master customer i cam give some name like pawan based that name master custoemr can access site pawan.abcd.com if customer open i can assign new theme

Answer (score 0):

below file public_html\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Store.php around line 607 you can find **getBaseurl()** function you can find

```
$url = $this->getConfig($path);
```

after this line added

```
$url = $this->newurl($url,$secure);
```

after created new function like below

```
public function newurl($url, $secure) {
        if (false !== strpos($url, self::BASE_URL_PLACEHOLDER)) {
            $url = str_replace(self::BASE_URL_PLACEHOLDER, $this->_request->getDistroBaseUrl(), $url);
        }
        $new_secure = $secure === null ? $this->isCurrentlySecure() : (bool) $secure;
        $path = $secure ? self::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL : self::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL;
        $new_url = $this->getConfig($path);
        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $new_host = parse_url($new_url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $subdomain_url = 'http';
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "on") {
            $subdomain_url .= "s";
        }
        $subdomain_url .= "://";
        if(isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) && isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){
            $servername = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
            $requesturi = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            $subdomain_url .= $servername . $servername;
            $subdomain_host = parse_url($subdomain_url, PHP_URL_HOST);
            $url = str_replace('://' . $host . '/', '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/', $url);
        } else{
            $url = $new_url;
        }


        return $url;

    }
```

now working as i expected